# How are stacked EXP bonuses applied?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

With KH: Final Mix, there are now accessories you can synthesize or receive that boost your EXP for defeating enemies. But if I have multiple of these equipped, how do they stack? For example, if I have an EXP Necklace, which gives +30%, and Donald has an EXP Ring, which gives plus +20%, do I end up with +50%, or do I end up with 30% * 20% (+56%)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be getting an EXP boost of plus 50%. I used to wonder the same thing so I equipped the items, killed an enemy worth a decent amount of exp and wrote it down and then killed the same enemy and got that down too. It ends up to be a boost of 50%. A good place to test it is Hollow Bastion just make a run through the last room (where the key hole entrance is) and pay attention to exp you gain with and with out the items. This place is also great for boosting levels, kill everything and then take gummy ship out and then directly back in to the save point near the last room, that's how I quickly got max level, though unintentionally since I was looking for the berserker shield for Goofy.